# Should I turn this code into own component if I am not sure whether I'd need to use it elsewhere?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a page in which I loop through an array of objects and render a `<p>` element for each element like this:

```
<p @click='selectCity(index)' v-for='(location, index) in locations'>
    {{ location.city }}, {{ location.country }}
</p>
```

This is just an example and in the future I might have to render more stuff than just a `<p>` element per object in the array. Should I make a component out of this and just v-for the component by passing the item to it?

Even though I've used Vue for about 3 weeks, I'm still a little fuzzy when should I make out a component of something and when should I not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't. You use a component if you need some component feature like local state, a computed for each item, or lifecycle hooks. Or, obviously, if you're using the block of code in multiple places.

I don't see any reason here to move to a component. When your requirements change, maybe you will need one.